# Minikube pod cannot access localhost service

Tags: minikube

I am running Minikube deployment where the pod [gitlab-runner] is trying to execute POST against a local gitlab API in my machine but it is getting the following error:

```
WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed                runner=3bS1tafj status=couldn't execute POST against http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/jobs/request: Post "http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/jobs/request": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed                runner=3bS1tafj status=couldn't execute POST against http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/jobs/request: Post "http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/jobs/request": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In K8S pods can communicate with each other using `localhost`, `localhost` is the network namespace **inside** the pod itself!!!!!

You can't use localhost to communicate from the pod to the "outside" world in this way.

#### What can you do?

- You can add `hostNetwork: true` to your Pods description.

> **HostNetwork** - Controls whether the pod may use the node network namespace.

- The `hostNetwork` setting applies to the Kubernetes pods.
  When a pod is configured with `hostNetwork: true`, **the applications running in such a pod can directly see the network interfaces of the host machine where the pod was started.**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
```

Comment: I added   hostNetwork: true in my deployment but still it showing this above error.

Comment: I am running a deployment where the pod[gitlab-runner] is trying to execute POST against a local gitlab api in my machine.

Comment: cluster admins won't be happy with `hostNetwork: true` in production cluster :)